# Trying to create XML file and got "TypeError: SubElement() got multiple values for argument 'tag'"

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

While the following code snippet of a python program generates a nice xml file:

```
from proc import create_SRXML  

create_SRXML.create_xml()
```

This following does not generate the xml file (the line "import pumoni.visu.renders as visua" is spoiling the job)

```
from proc import create_SRXML

import pumoni.visu.renders as visua

create_SRXML.create_xml()
```

and getting error log as follows:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "processor/analyze_all.py", line 26, in <module>
   create_SRXML.create_xml()
 File "/datas/repo/work/pul/process/create_SRXML.py", line 13, in     
create_xml

b1 = pulvii.SubElement(m1, "element",len="4", 
   name="FileMetaInformationGroupLength", tag="0002,0000", vm="1",
vr="UL")


TypeError: SubElement() got multiple values for argument 'tag'
```

May I know what the problem here is?

Comment: What are `proc` and `pumoni.visu.renders`? Please provide a [mcve].